# TypeScript: get type of instance method of class

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to get the type of an instance method of a class. Is there a built-in (better) way other than looking up the type in the prototype of the class?

```
class MyClass
{
    private delegate: typeof MyClass.prototype.myMethod; // gets the type ( boolean ) => number;

    public myMethod( arg: boolean )
    {
        return 3.14;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's probably the way to do it

Comment: But if this is done from outside the class, it will only work for public members.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you can use the following type:

```
type TypeOfClassMethod<T, M extends keyof T> = T[M] extends Function ? T[M] : never;
```

With that, you can write the following:

```
class MyClass
{
  private delegate: TypeOfClassMethod<MyClass, 'myMethod'>; // gets the type (boolean) => number;

  public myMethod( arg: boolean )
  {
    return 3.14;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can it be simplified to be just `MyClass["myMethod"]`? Is there any obvious drawback doing it this way as opposed to the one in the answer?

Comment: I think you'd have to write something similar to what Nitzan Tomer suggests in his answer: `typeof MyClass.prototype.myMethod`. I don't see drawbacks - just a different way to achieve this same thing.

Answer (score 48):

You could use TypeScript's built in [`InstanceType`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#instancetypet) for that:

```
class MyClass
{
  private delegate: InstanceType<typeof MyClass>['myMethod']; // gets the type (boolean) => number;

  public myMethod( arg: boolean )
  {
    return 3.14;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a cleaner solution compared to accepted answer, however it won't work if `MyClass` has generic type `MyClass<T>`. It's easier to just use `MyClass<T>['method']`

Answer (score 23):

A simple, idiomatic approach appears to be:

```
type MyMethodType = MyClass['myMethod'];
```

It doesn't seem to have any downsides, and, as [@cuddlefish points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45209142/typescript-get-type-of-instance-method-of-class#comment116129125_60950059), it also works if `MyClass` is generic.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to have a private method but still being able to pull this trick and have it have exposed as public then you can do this:

```
class MyClass {
    public myMethodType: typeof MyClass.prototype.myMethod;

    private myMethod(arg: boolean) {
        return 3.14;
    }
}

let fn: typeof MyClass.prototype.myMethodType;
```

That compiles to:

```
var MyClass = (function () {
    function MyClass() {
    }
    MyClass.prototype.myMethod = function (arg) {
        return 3.14;
    };
    return MyClass;
}());
var fn;
```

As you can see, the `myMethodType` member isn't part of the compiled js, which is good because it's only used for its type.