# Extract method type from an interface in Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

The `GoogleMap.d.ts` I am using looks like this:

```js
export declare class GoogleMap extends React.PureComponent<GoogleMapProps, GoogleMapState> {
    state: GoogleMapState;
    registeredEvents: google.maps.MapsEventListener[];
    mapRef: Element | null;
    getInstance: () => google.maps.Map<Element> | null;
    panTo: (latLng: google.maps.LatLng | google.maps.LatLngLiteral) => void;
    setMapCallback: () => void;
    componentDidMount(): void;
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps: GoogleMapProps): void;
    componentWillUnmount(): void;
    getRef: (ref: HTMLDivElement | null) => void;
    render(): React.ReactNode;
}
```

I am using `panTo` directly and would like to extract its type to use as a function type to avoid code duplication.

```
// Map Component
const Map = () => {
const [mapObj, setMapObj] = useState(null)
return 
<Map onLoad={(map) => setMapObj(map)}>
<Marker panTo={mapObj?.panTo.bind(mapObj)} />
</Map>
}

// Marker Component
// Bad - this duplicates the panTo type
type PanTo = (latLng: google.maps.LatLng | google.maps.LatLngLiteral) => void;

const Marker = ({panTo}) => <GoogleMarker panTo={panTo} />
```

I have looked into utilities such as `Pick` but they are going to return a subset of an interface when what I actually want is access a the type of a single method of an interface. Something like this would be ideal:

```
const Marker = ({panTo}: {panTo: Method<GoogleMap, 'panTo'>}) => <GoogleMarker panTo={panTo} />
```

Comment: possible duplicated of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45209142/typescript-get-type-of-instance-method-of-class

Comment: You just want a [lookup type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) of the form `GoogleMap["panTo"]`.  Note that I can't test that this works for your particular case because the code doesn't seem to be a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CLASS[MEMBER]` to get its type.

```js
const func: GoogleMap['panTo'] = (latLng) => {
  console.log(latLng);
};
```